# Issues in deploying .car file in wso2 esb

Tags: wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

I am creating the >car file using Developer  studio and deploying using Wso2 Carbon server4.0.
When i am deploying always getting the older versions. Some times the server not properly deploying the car. And also how to build the project to get the latest changes.

Please suggest me a better procedure creating and deploying the car file.

I am using Wso2 esb 4.7.0 version,
Developer studio 3.2 version.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the following documentation.

http://docs.wso2.org/display/DVS310/Deploying+and+Debugging